# Symfony\Component\Debug\Exception\FatalThrowableError (E_ERROR) Class 'Cart' not found

Tags: php, laravel, migration, eloquent

When calling a delete function on a product I get above error. The delete function works fine if i comment out the line where i detach the pivot table, however when deleting a product i would like to delete all entries in the pivot table as well. Does anyone know why this is happening?

The database has been migrated and seeded succesfully.

Pivot Table Migration:

```
<?php

use Illuminate\Support\Facades\Schema;
use Illuminate\Database\Schema\Blueprint;
use Illuminate\Database\Migrations\Migration;

class CreateOrderProductTable extends Migration
{
/**
 * Run the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function up()
{
    Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
        $table->integer('order_id');
        $table->integer('product_id');
        $table->float('price');
        $table->integer('amount');
        $table->primary(array('order_id', 'product_id'));
        $table->timestamps();
    });
}

/**
 * Reverse the migrations.
 *
 * @return void
 */
public function down()
{
    Schema::dropIfExists('orders_products');
}
}
```

Product Model:

```
<?php

namespace App;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Product extends Model
{
protected $fillable = ['name', 'price', 'stock', 'short_description', 'long_description'];

public function orders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_product', 'product_id', 'order_id');
}

public function carts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart', 'cart_product', 'product_id', 'cart_id');
}
}
```

Delete Function:

```
public function destroy($id)
{
    if ($this->validateID($id)) {
        $product = Product::find($id);
        //$product->carts()->detach(); --THE PROBLEMATIC LINE
        Product::destroy($id);
    }
    Session::flash('success', $product->name.' has been succesfully deleted.');
    return redirect()->to('/products');
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You did not provide a full namespace in your [`belongsToMany`](https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) relationship.

Probably something like that (unless you have subfolders for models):

```
public function orders() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Order', 'order_product', 'product_id', 'order_id');
}

public function carts() {
    return $this->belongsToMany('App\Cart', 'cart_product', 'product_id', 'cart_id');
}
```

Also, I would recommend adding this to your pivot migration:

```
Schema::create('order_product', function (Blueprint $table) {
    // Also, you would need to make `order_id` and `product_id` unsigned,
    // assuming your other `id` columns are `autoincrement` (which are unsigned by default)
    $table->integer('order_id')->unsigned();
    $table->integer('product_id')->unsigned();
    $table->float('price');
    $table->integer('amount');
    $table->primary(array('order_id', 'product_id'));
    $table->timestamps();

    // Adds foreign key to orders
    $table->foreign('order_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('orders')
        // Automatically deletes the pivot, when related order is deleted
        ->onDelete('cascade');

    // Adds foreign key to products
    $table->foreign('product_id')
        ->references('id')
        ->on('products')
        // Automatically deletes the pivot, when related cart is deleted
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
```

Also your table in `down()` part of migration mismatches the actual table name in the `up()` part.

Comment: I Tried this before, and didn't yield any results. However just tried it again and remigrated the database and it seems to work now. Must have forgotten to migrate last time.

Comment: count(): Parameter must be an array or an object that implements Countable now i get the following error, when i uncomment the line with detach.

Comment: Is the problem on the same line?

Comment: Yes it is on the same line. Everything works when it's commented out.

Comment: The line seems correct. Can you check that the relationship works by dumping the product cards: `dd($product->carts)` above the commented out line?

Comment: I edited the answer. I would recommend adding foreign keys to the pivot table and adding `->onDelete('cascade')`. That way you can avoid manually calling `->detach()` before deleting. Since SQL would take care of that automatically.

Comment: Getting error 1215 Cannot add foreign key constraint.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/169509/discussion-between-devk-and-luke-derkzen).